# Inserting a regex inside react's useState has no effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I am attempting to set a state's default value as a regex variable but the state isn't being set as this regex value. I assigned the regex to a variable and then isnerted that variable inside the useState default parameters but the default state isn't being set.

Here's my code and what i tried:

```
let allcategs = /women/i

const [catfilter, setCatfilter] = useState(allcategs) //the state of catfilter should be set to any string that is "women".

return(
<>
    {catfilter} //not showing anything
</>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't render an object directly as a React child
use the variable inside a function complete your operation and the render the result  Ex:

```
useEffect(() => {
            console.log(catfilter) // it will return the actual value

        }, [])
```

Comment: That's not what i need to do. I need to set the default state as catfilter

Comment: yes u can set that but you can't render it to the dom like that <>
    {catfilter} //not showing anything
</>

Comment: so how can you render it to the dom then?

Comment: push the result of the regex operation to an array and then map them to the dom

Comment: i just figured out a way for this problem you can use JSON.stringify(obj) then you can render objects to  react elements

Comment: thanks for your help, i also figured out another way to do it :)